# React .map is not a function when mapping prop array

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native

```
import React from 'react';
import { IProject } from '../interfaces/IProject';

export default function Table(projects : IProject[]) {
    return (
        <table className="table-fixed w-full">
            <thead className="bg-gray-200">
                <tr>
                    <th className="border px-4 py-2 w-12">#</th>
                    <th className="border px-4 py-2">Project Name</th>
                    <th className="border px-4 py-2">abc</th>
                    <th className="border px-4 py-2">xyz</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                {projects.map((project) => 
                    <tr>
                        <td key = {project.id} className="border px-4 py-2">{project.name}</td>
                        <td key = {project.id} className="border px-4 py-2">{project.totalHours}</td>
                    </tr>
                )}  
            </tbody>
        </table>
    );
}
```

I'm getting the runtime error : "TypeError: projects.map is not a function" and I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Typo man, it should be `function Table({ projects : IProject[] })` <- notice the brace?

Comment: @hackape if I do that, I get another error : "Binding element 'IProject' implicitly has an 'any' type"

Comment: `function Table({ projects } : { projects : IProject[] })` fix

Comment: Looks like you need to put more effect into learning both react and typescript

Comment: @hackape Thank you, that worked!, I've just started learning React. If you add an answer I will accept it.

Comment: Thanks you, but I'll pass.